# limesurvey - autofill token from another php app

Tags: limesurvey

In Limesurvey, a user can take a survey if he exist in database and have a valid token
based on an internal user database, how to autocomplete the token in limesurvey based on the token generated from the first application

Answer (score 1):

Use LimeSurvey API see example : https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API#PHP_Example

And the part to create a new participant : https://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_add_participants

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to:

1. Check if token exists
2. If not, create new token
3. Redirect to survey with token

https://www.limesurvey.org/forum/can-i-do-this-with-limesurvey/110439-create-token-on-the-fly?start=15#158184